# How to show NULL in graphql result if the field is empty

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, strapi

I'm using Strapi as cms for my frontend page in Gatsby.

In Strapi I have a content-type `Pages`. The `Pages` content-type is many to many relations to all other content types.

Thus I have content types as follows:

- Pages
- Footers
- Headers

For query as follows:

```
query MyQuery {
  allStrapiPage {
    edges {
      node {      
        footers {
          name
        }
        headers {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting all results as I should get.

Thus, the result is as follows:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allStrapiPage": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "footers": [
              {
                "name": "Footer ONE"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "headers": [
              {
                "name": "Header one"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
     ]
   }
  }
}
```

But if I do not have any records in `footers` or `headers` content type for the query above I get an error as follows:

```
"Cannot query field \"footers\" on type \"StrapiPage\".
```

That is not what I want. How can I get null on the field that not exists? Thus if `footers` content type is empty, I expect result as follows:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allStrapiPage": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "footers": null
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "headers": [
              {
                "name": "Header one"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
     ]
   }
  }
}
```

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't used strapi, but do you have control over  strapi backend?

Comment: @RakeshJain Only via their admin panel.

Comment: If it is possible then you can create resolver on API for the footer, where you can check for data if present and if not return null. Also if you return null for footer you need to make sure that footer is not strict in the schema, otherwise, it will error out too.

Comment: This is not a solution but an "easy" workaround I decided to go with when facing this similar problem (using Contentful, not Strapi). I defined "placelholders" for every content-type I have. All these placeholders are defined with all their attributes filled. Then, when I get the content from `gatsby-node` to create the pages, I have a conditional that checks if the item being iterated is one of these placeholders and, if so, it just disregards it.

Answer (score 0):

I just joined and can't comment on posts yet so I'll put this in the answer section. Did you check that in your schema you defined footers and headers as nullable fields? That could be causing your error